# Most efficient way to group by 3rd level and access columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to take a pandas dataframe that has a multiindex and multiple columns. I want to find the most efficient way to loop through the columns by the 3rd multi index. I was thinking of unstacking but I can't figure out how to access them by that index. Is there a better way(faster processing wise):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([{'Index_A':2018,'Index_B':0,'Index_C':101,'Col_D':0.3,'Col_E':.4},{'Index_A':2019,'Index_B':0,'Index_C':101,'Col_D':0.3,'Col_E':.4},{'Index_A':2019,'Index_B':0,'Index_C':102,'Col_D':0.3,'Col_E':.4}])

df = df.set_index(['Index_A','Index_B','Index_C'])
df = df.unstack()

for Index_C in [101,102]:
    # get dataframe with index of ['Index_A','Index_B'] and columns ['Col_D,'Col_E']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the cross-section at each value:

```
for i in df.index.levels[2].unique():
    print(df.xs(i, level=2))
```

Or if it's not important not to have the third level in the index, you can do:

```
for i, j in df.groupby(level=2).groups.items():
    print(df.loc[j])
```

Comment: The cross section method it what I as doing but I was hoping that doing in a different method like the group by you mention will be significantly faster. Going to give that a try.

Comment: I tested the groupby method and it seems about 2x faster then xs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pd.DataFrame.query`:

```
for i in df.index.get_level_values(2).unique():
    print(df.query(f'Index_C == {i}'))

                         Col_D  Col_E
Index_A Index_B Index_C              
2018    0       101        0.3    0.4
2019    0       101        0.3    0.4

                         Col_D  Col_E
Index_A Index_B Index_C              
2019    0       102        0.3    0.4
```

If you really want to drop the final `MultiIndex` label, you can do so:

```
for i in df.index.get_level_values(2).unique():
    res = df.query(f'Index_C == {i}')   
    res.index = res.index.droplevel(2)  
    print(res)

                 Col_D  Col_E
Index_A Index_B              
2018    0          0.3    0.4
2019    0          0.3    0.4

                 Col_D  Col_E
Index_A Index_B              
2019    0          0.3    0.4
```